# Unity paste <ALL> components recursively to parent and all sub-children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to edit an existing component copier for the sake of copying the components over to a new game object all with the same name.

Components are successfully recursively returned with

```
static Component[] copiedComponents;

static void Copy(){
   copiedComponents = UnityEditor.Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>();
}
```

pasting is done with

```
foreach(var targetGameObject in UnityEditor.Selection.gameObjects) {
  if (!targetGameObject)
    continue;

  Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(targetGameObject, targetGameObject.name + ": Paste All Components");

  foreach(var copiedComponent in copiedComponents) {
    if (!copiedComponent)
      continue;

    UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.CopyComponent(copiedComponent);

    var targetComponent = targetGameObject.GetComponent(copiedComponent.GetType());

    if (targetComponent) // if gameObject already contains the component
    {
      if (UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.PasteComponentValues(targetComponent)) {
        Debug.Log("Successfully pasted: " + copiedComponent.GetType());
      } else {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to copy: " + copiedComponent.GetType());
      }
    } else // if gameObject does not contain the component
    {
      if (UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.PasteComponentAsNew(targetGameObject)) {
        Debug.Log("Successfully pasted: " + copiedComponent.GetType());
      } else {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to copy: " + copiedComponent.GetType());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It correctly grabs every component of the parent and every single nested child, but when pasting it will only paste it on the selected parent.
Do I need to store it in a dictionary with keyvalues of the gameObject name and a list of the components or something like that?

Any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you paste into

```
var targetComponent = targetGameObject.GetComponent(copiedComponent.GetType());
```

This only looks for components on **this** target object!

There is no bubbling down any hierarchy like `GetComponentsInChildren` does

You would basically have to  check if the target object's hierarchy even matches at all and look for the correct child object.

For that you would need to additionally store the path to those child objects. You can use [`AnimationUtility.CalculateTransformPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.CalculateTransformPath.html) like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

private class ComponentInfo
{
    public Component Component { get; }
    public string Path { get; }

    public ComponentInfo(Component component string path)
    {
        Component = component;
        Path = path;
    }
}

static ComponentInfo[] copiedComponents;

static void Copy()
{
   var sourceRootObject = UnityEditor.Selection.activeGameObject;
   // added 'true' to also include inactive
   copiedComponents = sourceRootObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>(true)
      // for each component store along with the path
      .Select(c => new ComponentInfo(c, AnimationUtility.CalculateTransformPath(c.transform, sourceRootObject.transform)))
      .ToArray();
}
```

And then later now that you have the paths stored you can use [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) to try and find that object on the receiving side

```
foreach(var targetGameObject in UnityEditor.Selection.gameObjects) 
{
    if (!targetGameObject) continue;

    Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(targetGameObject, targetGameObject.name + ": Paste All Components");

    foreach(var copiedComponent in copiedComponents) 
    {
        if (!copiedComponent.Component) continue;

        // Try to find target child object
        GameObject targetObject = null;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(copiedComponent.Path))
        {
            // No path -> root object itself
            targetObject = targetGameObject;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise try and find child
            var child = targetGameObject.transform.Find(copiedComponent.Path); 
            if(!child) 
            { 
                Debug.LogError($"Couldn't find {copiedComponent.Path} within {targetGameObject}");
                continue;
            }

            // If you also want to actually create according children
            // I will leave this as a homework for you
            // basically you would need to split the path on '/' and for each of those check if
            // according child exists and if not create it ;)

            targetObject = child.gameObject;
        }

        // From now on below make sure to use 'targetObject' everywhere instead of 'targetGameObject'

        UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.CopyComponent(copiedComponent.Component);

        var type = copiedComponent.Component.GetType();

        if(targetObject.TryGetComponent(type, out var targetComponent))
        {
            // if gameObject already contains the component
            if (UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.PasteComponentValues(targetComponent)) 
            {
                Debug.Log($"Successfully pasted: {type}");
            } 
            else 
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Failed to copy: {type)}");
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            // if gameObject does not contain the component
            if (UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.PasteComponentAsNew(targetObject))
            {
                Debug.Log($"Successfully pasted: {type}");
            }
            else 
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Failed to copy: {type}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing reply, unfortunately ComponentInfo runs into an error without inheriting MonoBehaviour. When I inherit Monobehaviour to ComponentInfo, an exception is thrown "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed. MonoBehavious can only be added using AddComponent()."

The culprit seems to be `.Select(c => new ComponentInfo()`, but I'm unsure how to refactor it. I'm not familiar with linq

Comment: Edit: It seems to work regardless of the error, so, wow! That's pretty incredible. Is it possible to do this without requiring the children to have the same name?

Comment: `ComponentInfo` should definitely **NOT** inherit `MonoBehaviour` .. what is the original error you get? I think I ratzher just forgot to change `copiedComponent.GetType()` to `copiedComponent.Component.GetType()` ;) ^^ was typing that on the phone

Comment: `Is it possible to do this without requiring the children to have the same name` how else would you know then which component belongs on which child? You could of course as well store and look via the childrens indices .. it will be way harder though since you need to store entire index paths (e.g. as a `List<int>`) to say it like that so e.g. something like `1, 0, 0, 3` would mean you later apply the component to `root.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetChild(3).gameObject` .. you would of course need to check whether these exist again .. or simply wrap everything in `try-catch`

Comment: you would basically for each element from `GetomponentInChildren` have to recursively bubble up the `transform.parent` until finding the root object and keep track of the `transform.GetSiblingIndex` in the list but backwards ;)

Comment: Oh you're right. I'm such a dummy sometimes. Console was yelling at me to include MonoBehaviour to ComponentInfo, so I just did it without really thinking about it. Removing MonoBehaviour and changing `copiedComponent.GetType()` to `copiedComponent.Component.GetType()` resolved the issue! I'd like to thank you again for the help, and I'm going to get to work on trying to implement it without the children's names needing to be the same (sometimes Unity likes to change children from Cube.001 to Cube_001 etc)